# In python lists removing similar or close values and writing only once

Tags: python, list, data-analysis

I am new to python. I have 2 lists: (Note: in each cycle the values and number of items in lists will be different)

```
x = [340, 730, 341]

y = [900, 600, 902]
```

Where 340,770, and 341 are x1,x2, and x3 respectively: and 900,600, and 902 are y1,y2, and y3 respectively.

(Note: x and y represent x and y axis values of a point in graph)

is there any way to write the close values only once? For example, values of (x1, y1) are almost equal to (x3,y3) so the code should pick any of (x1,y1) or (x3,y3) not the both.

In given case output should be:

```
x = [340, 730]

y = [900, 600]
```

OR

```
x = [730, 341]

y = [600, 902]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (x,y) data. You want to filter depending on the difference between (`xi,yi`) and (`xj,yj`).

Since you want to consider both (x,y) at once, you may want to use a Root Mean Square (RMS) comparison.

We will say that below 1% RMS difference, then you keep (x,y) at the lower index, and eliminate (x,y) at greater index.

To make that operation with the information you provided, the following code should work, although not optimal and will certainly be slow on huge datasets.

Still:

```
from math import sqrt

x = [340, 730, 341, 227]

y = [900, 600, 902, 765]

c = 0.01

l = []

ox = []
yx = []

for v in zip(x,y):

    c_rms = sqrt(v[0]**2+v[1]**2)

    for rms in l:
        if abs(c_rms/rms - 1) < c:
            break
    else:
        l.append(c_rms)
        ox.append(v[0])
        yx.append(v[1])

print (ox)
print (yx)
```

Output:

```
[340, 730, 227]
[900, 600, 765]
```

The list `l` is used to store rms values. For each tuple `(xi,yi)` or `v`, we calculate the RMS and we look in the list `l`: if there is a difference less than cutoff `c` (0.01 so 1% here) with an index we saved already, then we do not save the current index/RMS (`c_rms`) and so we do not save the elements in the tuple `v` to output lists `ox` (`v[0]`) and `oy` (`v[1]`).

Also, note the use of the `for ... else` statement. If the loop terminates with no `break`, then the `else` will follow. If the loop breaks, then we skip the `else`. Less well known feature, sometimes useful.

Comment: Thanks Synthase, it's working. I have a question from above code that how "rms" value is calculated in the first cycle, as "l" is empty in first cycle. Also I was thinking that "c_rms" will become "rms" in the next cycle but it is showing different value in the next cycle. So, if you can please tell about "rms" calculation.

Comment: You're right: at the beginning, "l" is empty. So the first tuple (and lowest index) will always be saved. But that is not a problem it is fully consistent with what you want. Then, you re almost right, c_rms will be ONE OF the rms at the next tuple. Since you store all "accepted" c_rms in l and that l is a list, l will contain more than one rms value. If you print (l) at the end, you ll see all c_rms saved and so all rms you test when you loop and compare the next c_rms to the list of rms. Hope that s clear!